# OSX kext: Can't open IOResouces in ::start() due to owned by some other

Tags: macos, virtualization, iokit, kernel-extension

part of my work over the least years is USB virtulization under OSX and I found myself confused once again in front of a closed door.

One of the first steps my kext (derived from IOUSBControllerV3) like to do is, after my provider (IOResources, because I'm virtuall) called my ::start() (::init() done), inside super class, to try a provider->open(this).

This is the normal way and works fine till the day, another (not from me) virtualisation kext is already loaded. Then the call failed and in consequence my ::start() and the kext installation failed at all (is non functional).

Grabbing the source code of the IOService class and get inforamtion by
provider->isOpen() is true and provider->isOpen(this) is false 
IOResouces seemed to be owned by the other (virtulisation) kext. 
Which means the IOService internal __owner is occupied exclusive by some other.

How can this be?? 
How can IOResources be handle only one __owner at one time?

The provider->open() call is done inside my base class IOUSBController::start()
and is still keep open till ::stop() is called, which means end of life.

The failure returns from the call provider->open(this) inside my super class IOUSBController::start() inside my ::start() and depends on if another kext with provider IOResources is already loaded or not.

At this state there can't be any resouces conflict, because it is the very beginning of loading the kext. And in my imagination there can't be any resource conflict at all, because all is virtuall.

Or is it true, that IOResources can only handle (be provider for) one kext?

No, unbelievable. 
My next idea was, that the foreigen kext is bad implemented (it's not perfect, because kextunload is not possible) but the provider->open(this) and ->close(this) calls are done in the holy apple base classes, which must be correct.

Sorry, lot of text and thanks in advance for any constructive comment.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a good reason why you need to `open()` IOResources? The point of `open()` in the context of `IOService`s is specifically for providing exclusive or at least reserved access to resources which don't support an arbitrary number of clients. (e.g. a physical device can usually only have one driver loaded) IOResources is a dummy service which doesn't provide any features apart from the `publishResource`/`resourceMatching` mechanism. I'm not aware of any reason why you'd need to call `open()` on it.

**Edit:** I'd missed that the call to `open()` is made by Apple's superclass, not the asker's code. In this case, as with any base classes that have special requirements on a provider object, I recommend writing your own provider class. This provider class can be a client of IOResources, and the driver with the fussy base class can be a client of it.

Comment: Hi, the provider->open() call is not  from my source, but inside the ::start(provider) function of my superclass IOUSBCrontroller which I must call. As you know for derived classes with overloaded base methods you have to call the superclass method inside your overloading function. You are right, between the open(this) and close(this) you have an exclusive access to IOService (__owner = this). What I expected was a forked or cloned provider IOResources instance, but there seemed to be one instance for all?  ...Part II follow

Comment: ... Because the real system USBController (provider is PCI class) uses the same library I expect a resource conflict only for physical resources (pci, bus addresses,...) but IOResource should be able to hold a lot of instances parallel.  Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Ahhh, I see now. You are probably best off creating a dummy IOService object to sit between the IOResources and your USB controller subclass. Your dummy device can then create the controller and the controller will call open() on the dummy, not IOResources directly.

Comment: Very clever idea! Little bit afraid that calling IOUSBController::start(dummy_IOService) will confuse further communication, because to open(provider) is not the only thing which is done with it. But I'll try it, thanks so far.

Comment: Yeah, you will need to code your "dummy" to be the equivalent of the `IOPCIDevice` that normally acts as the provider to the XHCI/EHCI implementations of `IOUSBController*`. I don't know the internals of the USB controller classes, but if they expect anything fancy of the provider (interrupts, etc.) then you'll almost certainly want to have a custom provider class rather than relying on IOResources anyway. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately the next days I'm ob duty with other tasks, but took a look into IOUSBController.cpp and I'm much in doubt if this can work, 'cause the provider and his workloop are one main communcation channel with the system. The apple dev. docs recommended strongly to use IOResources as provider for all (not only USB) virtualization, but we see the that it is not even able to handle two USBController classes?  By the way, IRQs and other physically based events are no problem, because we are full virtuall (the real USB device is outside in the network on some special device). Is this odd?

Comment: You're still effectively using IOResources as a provider for your "virtual device", which then acts as the provider for your IOUSBController. This is pretty common. For example, if you mount 2 disk images, you'll find that there is one `IOHDIXController`, which uses IOResources as the provider. The IOHDIXController then acts as the provider for two `IOHDIXHDDriveOutKernel` objects, one for each virtual drive, which in turn act as providers for the actual storage device subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Following Phils (pmdj) very constructive proposals, he is obviously a member of the apple kext IOKit olymp, a simple enhancement seems to fix my problem.

In ::start(provider) I create (OSTypeAlloc()) a dummy IOService class dumprov,
make dumprov->init() and dumprov->start(provider) and then call my superclass IOUSBController::start(dumprov) with success:-)

When I'm called finaly to ::stop(), I call IOUSBController::stop(dumprov) and make a dumprov->release(). Fine!

Many thanks to pmdj!!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted!